# How can I see debug messages with Mono apps?

Tags: c#, mono, debugging

I have various Debug.WriteLine messages, I tried to see those messages using export MONO_DEBUG_LEVEL=debug, but I end up getting other irrelevant debug messages which was not outputted by my code.

What should I do to see the debug messages?

I'm using Linux :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run it with the wrapper mono --debug

Answer (score 0):

Debug messages are probably streamed to the error output (stderr). You can stream those to the standard output (stdout) by appending `2>&1`. You can obviously do the reverse with `1>&2` as 1 refers to stdout and 2 to stderr.

**Summary**
For piping stderr to stdout:

```
mono <youapp> 2>&1
```

For piping stderr and stdout to stdout:

```
mono <youapp> &>&1
```

Comment: [nubela@nubela-netbook Debug]$ mono subsync.exe --n test/ lalala 2>&1 -> doesn't work :(

Comment: @nubela Do you already have a solution? I'm running in the same on OS/X